# Hg Pull vs. Update to branch tip

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Using TortoiseHg Synchronize, clicking "Pull" pulls down the *2nd most recent* revision.

At the bottom of the Synchronize interface is a button, "Update to branch tip."  Clicking this button pulls down the most recent revision.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Command line hg tells this:

> $ hg help pull

...

```
Pull changes from a remote repository to a local one.
```

...

```
-R is specified). By default, this does not update the copy of the
project in the working directory.
```

vs.

> $ hg help up

...

> Update the repository's working directory to the specified
>   revision, or the tip of the current branch if none is specified.

Comment: To build on @ptman's comments, you can pull and update in a single operation by using the `-u` flag, so `$ hg pull -u [source]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to mercurial or want to know you havent missed any options, this is could be helpful:

http://blog.hanxiaogang.com/hg-guide/

Comment: Cerberrussian, this is not an answer, it should be a comment. At the very least, please try to put some of the content of that blog in your "answer" so that T.Stone doesn't have to visit an external link to get his answer.